Bottom Navbar Position For React Native Web is Inconsistent across browsers
I am working on an app in react native for three platforms (web, android & ios). on ios and android, the bottom navbar has the same spacing from the bottom. But on web, the spacing changes from one browser to another.
On Samsung Internet Browser
enter image description here
On Chrome
enter image description here
The behavior is similar for safari and chrome on ios.
Any assistance will be highly appreciated 
I have tried updating the spacing depending on the browser, but it is still inconsistent across different browsers.
Below is the function I am using to find the browser of the user.
const getBrowserInfo = () => {
  if (Platform.OS !== "web") return "native";

  if (typeof window === "undefined" || typeof navigator === "undefined") {
    return "server";
  }

  const userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

  if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
    return "iOS";
  }
  if (/Safari/.test(userAgent) && !/Chrome/.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Safari";
  }
  if (/Chrome/.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Chrome";
  }
  if (/Firefox/.test(userAgent)) {
    return "Firefox";
  }
  return "Other";
};

Below is where I am using the browser info to add space to the bottom.
tabBar: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    borderRadius: 32,
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: Platform.select({
      web: (() => {
        const browser = getBrowserInfo();
        const isSmallScreen = screenWidth < 720;
        if (!isSmallScreen) {
          return getVh(1); // 1vh equivalent
        }
        if (browser === "Safari" || browser === "ios") {
          return getVh(20); // 20vh equivalent
        }
        if (browser === "Chrome" || browser === "Firefox") {
          return getVh(12);
        }
        return getVh(7); // Default fallback 7vh
      })(),
      default: getVh(1.6), // 1.6vh equivalent for native platforms
    }),

    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowRadius: 15,
    elevation: 5,
    paddingVertical: 16,
    paddingHorizontal: 12,
    zIndex: 1000,
  },

